# Returning Laravel view after executing another function results in blank page

Tags: php, laravel, string, function

I have the following Laravel functions

```
public function addNewPhotoRequest($uuid) {
    $photos = DB::table('photos')->where('uuid', '=', request('qr_code'))->get();

    $new_photo_request = new Photos;
    $new_photo_request->uuid = $uuid;
    $new_photo_request->save();
        
    $this->submitPhotoRequest($new_photo_request->photo_id);
}
```

After executing the $this->submitPhotoRequest line, the function will not return the
view. I can't return any views nor perform any redirects using the "Return Redirect XXX". It works fine if I put these statements in the addNewPhotoRequest function so I know there is nothing wrong with my views or routes. Any ideas? All that is returned is a blank white page with no errors reported. I can do a DD("test") on the submit photo request function, so I know the function works and is going to it correctly.

```
/**
 * Submit the API code if it matches a valid code within the database. 
 * This will allow the user to upload a photo and associate it with a database record.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function submitPhotoRequest($photo_id)
{
    return view('upload_photo', ['api_code' => $photo_id]);      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `addNewPhotoRequest` is the method being declared in the route, then you are missing the `return`....

Your code should be like this:

```php
public function addNewPhotoRequest($uuid) {
    $photos = DB::table('photos')->where('uuid', '=', request('qr_code'))->get();

    $new_photo_request = new Photos;
    $new_photo_request->uuid = $uuid;
    $new_photo_request->save();
        
    return $this->submitPhotoRequest($new_photo_request->photo_id);
}
```

Comment: Ah that was it. Thanks for that! Can't believe something so simple. Working perfectly now.